# best way to refactor hardcoded links in rails update methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, refactoring

Having some "complex" routing, what would be a good way to clean below hardcoded links up and make them named routes? I have these kind of constructions on several locations and want to get them out of the code.

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
  def update

    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @tags = Session.tag_counts_on(:tags)
    @profile.form = params[:form]
    @match = Match.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
    authorize! :update, @profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        format.html { redirect_to "/me/#{ current_user.username }/edit/#{ @profile.form }", notice: t('notice.saved') }
      else
        format.html { render action: "/edit/edit_" + params[:profile][:form], :what => @profile.form }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own named routes by setting the `:as` attribute.

So, for the successful update redirect you must have a route that looks something like `post '/me/:user/edit/:form.format' => 'profiles#show'

Just put `, :as => :profiles` at the end of the route and you can redirect to: `profile_path(:user => current_user.username, :form => @profile.form)` instead.

Running `rake routes` after the route change will give you list of what named routes you can use.